# Yii2 Database Schema Best Practices

Tags: database, schema, yii2

Where should I put my SQL schema script(s) in Yii 2? Is there an official best practice?

Yii 1 put SQL scripts in the `data` directory, which Yii 2 doesn't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually these folder and schemas are used only for demonstration purposes.

Personally in case of existence of such schemas I would probably put them also in `data` folder.

But I din't see any official recommendations for this.

It's kind of personal preference. Just choose the convention that suitable for you and your team and follow it.

You did not mention what kind of schemas they are, maybe it's better just use [migrations](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-migrations.html)?

I also remembered similar [question](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57591-where-do-you-put-business-logic-besides-models) about placing `components` on official forum. And the answer from `samdark` (one of the main framework contributors) is:

> Just add more classes. It doesn't matter which directory are these
>   placed into or if these are components or plain PHP classes.

I guess with schemas it's even more simple. Just organize it the way you feel comfortable.